# Nested Json in Table - React-Virtualized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using Table from 'react-virtualized'.

I receive some nested data that I want to display inside my custom Row.
My problem is to bind nested json to my Column dataKey.

```
    data= 
  {
    name:'Chris',
    age:'15',
    adresse : {
       number:'14',
       street: 'xxx'
               } 
   }
```

My Column

```
<Column dataKey="name"    [....] />
<Column dataKey="age" [...] />
<Column dataKey=" ??????" />  // adresse.number ?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just supply a `cellDataGetter` value for the 3rd column.

If you only have the 1 field it could be like:

```
<Column
  cellDataGetter={({ rowData }) => rowData.address.number}
  dataKey="adresse"
/>
```

If you want to display more than one it could be more like:

```
<Column
  cellDataGetter={({ dataKey , rowData }) => rowData.address[dataKey]}
  dataKey="number"
/>
<Column
  cellDataGetter={({ dataKey , rowData }) => rowData.address[dataKey]}
  dataKey="street"
/>
```

Comment: I ddin't see cellDataGetter props ! Very usefull.
Thanks as always brian !